# How can I programmatically alter CSS to limit its scope?

Tags: javascript, css, abstract-syntax-tree, css-parsing

I've got a chunk of CSS as a string, and I want to insert it into the DOM such that it only applies to elements in a particular container. Some tools, like Polymer, for example, rewrite CSS selectors so they only apply within a limited scope. How can I do something similar so that, when I insert this CSS into the DOM, it won't change all elements on the page?

To make it more concrete, imagine the following HTML and CSS from an external source:

```
<style>p { font-size: 20px; }</style>
<p>Boo.</p>
```

I want to insert these elements into a `#container` element, but I don't want to change the font-size for all `<p>` elements. I'd like to rewrite all the selectors inside that `<style>` element so they only apply within `#container` (`p` -> `#container p`, etc.). How?

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/reworkcss/css to parse the CSS, then alter selectors, and finally stringify:

```
const CSS = require('css');

function scopeCSS(css, scope) {
  const ast = CSS.parse(css);
  for (let rule of ast.stylesheet.rules) {
    if (rule.type == 'rule') {
      rule.selectors = rule.selectors.map(selector => `${scope} ${selector}`);
    }
  }
  return CSS.stringify(ast);
}

scopeCSS('div { color: black; }', '#foo');
// #foo div {
//   color: black;
// }
```

http://requirebin.com/?gist=trevordixon/839d0674531dafa98fb95ae51474245e

Comment: interesting so with this you can change any behaviour of css selector?can be more specific of how exactly you are achieveing this behaviour

Comment: reworkcss/css is a CSS parser that takes in CSS as a string and returns an object describing the stylesheet. By modifying that object and passing it back to `CSS.stringify`, I can reliably change all the selectors.